# WPF Animation Binding Breaks

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-4.0

I'm working with WPF 3D and applied translation animation to a Cube.

```
        DoubleAnimation tranlateAnimationX = new DoubleAnimation(from.X, to.X, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));

        DoubleAnimation tranlateAnimationY = new DoubleAnimation(from.X, to.Y, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));

        DoubleAnimation tranlateAnimationZ = new DoubleAnimation(from.X, to.Z, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));


        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tranlateAnimationX, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetXProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(tranlateAnimationX, "translateTransform");

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tranlateAnimationY, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetYProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(tranlateAnimationY, "translateTransform");

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tranlateAnimationZ, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetZProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(tranlateAnimationZ, "translateTransform");
```

This animation works perfectly until i explicitly change the transformation value (The value the animation is changing) of the cube in another part of the code.

After i change the transformation value the animation stopped working.

Please provide a solution to keep the animation binding in place even when i change the value explicitly.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `Storyboard.Begin()` after transformation value has changed to restart the Storyboard.

Comment: Tried it like that. Still the same issue.